# Emacs C/C++ comment filling: want paragraphs in comment to not be merged

Tags: c++, c, emacs

Input

```
// This is an example, a test, of what I want emacs filling, in this case of C++ comments, to do.
// This is a paragraph that needs to get filled.
//     But I want to start a new paragraph, within the same comment, that is indented,
// but not joined to the previous by filling.
//     And another.
```

Here is what I get with my current settings.  I do not want this. It joins paragraphs.

```
// This is an example, a test, of what I want emacs filling,
// in this case of C++ commentrs to do.  This is a paragraph
// that needs to get filled.  But I want to start a new
// paagraph, within the same comment, that is indented, but
// not joined the the previous by filling.  And another.
```

Here is what I want

```
// This is an example, a test, of what I want emacs filling,
// in this case of C++ comments to do.  This is a paragraph
// that needs to get filled.
//     But I want to start a new paragraph, within the same
// comment, that is indented, but not joined to the previous
// by filling.
//     And another.
```

Using adaptive fill.

Gnu emacs 24.1.1

---

Somebody asked "How is emacs to distinguish your nonstandard paragraph marker from a user who was a bit sloppy with spaces? The standard marker for a new paragraph is a blank line."

There are emacs modes that can properly fill paragraphs with standard English indentation, where the first line of new paragraphs has more indentation than paragraph body lines nearby.

```
This is an example, a test, of what I want emacs filling,
in this case of non-comments to do.  This is a paragraph
that needs to get filled.
    But I want to start a new paragraph, within the same
comment, that is indented, but not joined to the previous
by filling.
    And another.
```

All I want is to extend this to extra indentation, past a fill prefix.

Comment: Could you tell us what you're doing to join the lines?

Comment: @Alan: I do not understand the question: or, rather, I think I understand the question, but it is irrelevant. You seem to be asking what electric-c-mode key I am pressing. Forget that: I am asking about reformatting a block of ascii text. Newlines at end of libe, etc.

Comment: @KrazyGlew it have been asked three years ago, did you found an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can control this through various [regex variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Paragraphs.html).  you can probably get it to do what you want, but it's a bit of an "art".